# Parse Server Javascript support nested select() calls not working

Tags: javascript, parse-server

I'm attempting to speed up one of my parse server queries by selecting only the attributes that I need. I've been using select and it works fine for attributes on the top level. I'm curious if select can work on nested data.

For example:

```
{
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: {d: 3, e: 4},
    f: 5
}
```

Using select('a') on this object would return {a:1}, and select('c') would return {c: {d: 3, e: 4}}. I'm wondering if it is possible to use select in a way that returns nested data without it's parent.

eg. how do you return {d: 3} only?

Comment: Give us a few more examples of what you're trying to accomplish. With that data, what should `select('a')`, `select('c')` and `select('d')` return.

Comment: It just returns the selected key and its value. I added in examples above.

Comment: Then how are you getting `{d: 3}`?

Comment: That's my question. I want to get only {d:3}. When I run select('c') it returns c (the key) and {d: 3, e: 4} (its value). I want only {d: 3}, not {e:4} as well

Comment: Alright, I need you to fill in the blanks here please. `select('a') should return _`, `select('c') should return _`, `select('d') should return _`. Edit your question above (Don't type a comment), and put exactly what each of those calls **should** return. Don't put "I only want X", just put "this block of code, should return this result" like I have outlined here.

Comment: Haha I think you should reread my question. those are already there :)

Comment: Trust me: If they did, I wouldn't be asking the question. When you ask "How do you return `{d: 3}` only, you don't specify which parameters I should be passing in to get that. Please clarify.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding you correctly? The question already states what select('a') and select('c') return. I'm not necessarily interested in what select('d') returns. I will repeat my question again: 'how do you return {d: 3} only?' I don't know 'which parameters I should be passing in to get that' because that is exactly my question

Comment: Return a new object `return {d: obj.c.d}`

Comment: Our misunderstanding might be in that I'm talking specifically about parse server queries: https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#query-constraints (scroll down to 'select'). Not just pulling data off of a JSON object

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.select('c.d')` in order to only get the data from the `d` object.

See the tests here: https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/blob/master/spec/ParseQuery.spec.js#L3439